# Trying to define a function to iterate through rows of different data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a function to run through my dataframes as part of my model which will apply the code based on conditions through each row for each period (1-48) first and then another function to apply it to each day (8 days for now and more later when I scale it up) in my dataset.

EDIT: to explain my logic as I understand loops like this can be the least efficient way, at the moment the data is looking at one weeks worth of data, whereas eventually it will be looking at a longer period so I am after something that scales it up efficiently.

My first dataframe is ("merit_order"):

|  | BM Unit ID 1 | Technology_x | ave rank | rank | rank of plants | gas_quantile | coal_quantile | Technology_y | 1 | 2 | ... | 39 | 40 | 41 | 42 | 43 | 44 | 45 | 46 | 47 | 48 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | FAWN-1 | CCGT | 2.5 | 1 | 1 | 0 | NaN | CCGT | 130.5957 | 131.07 | ... | 129.73 | 129.63 | 129.9833 | 130.1397 | 130.1533 | 130.0467 | 130.403 | 130.4063 | 130.1733 | 130.2863 |
| 1 | GRAI-6 | CCGT | 5.666667 | 2 | 2 | 0 | NaN | CCGT | 345.44 | 355.96 | ... | 408.0333 | 402.6 | 393.95 | 376.7167 | 354.7333 | 345.9 | 355.5333 | 330.55 | 322.95 | 333.66 |
| 2 | EECL-1 | CCGT | 7 | 3 | 3 | 0 | NaN | CCGT | 343.44 | 404.496 | ... | 436.0032 | 397.0944 | 354.528 | 438.948 | 420.732 | 400.644 | 415.836 | 388.656 | 314.172 | 253.908 |
| 3 | PEMB-21 | CCGT | 7.166667 | 4 | 4 | 0 | NaN | CCGT | 364.8667 | 428.3333 | ... | 401.1667 | 408.0333 | 400.8667 | 388.5 | 399.3667 | 367.55 | 367.92 | 354.2 | 370.725 | 406.2667 |
| 4 | PEMB-51 | CCGT | 7.2 | 5 | 5 | 0 | NaN | CCGT | 370.65 | 370.45 | ... | 433.64 | 435.24 | 435 | 422.36 | 430.96 | 428.32 | 376.8 | 427.85 | 332.7 | 358.4 |
| 5 | PEMB-41 | CCGT | 8.333333 | 6 | 6 | 0 | NaN | CCGT | 368.7333 | 426.3333 | ... | 429 | 428.7667 | 428.6333 | 429.2333 | 425.3333 | 422.9667 | 368.1833 | 357.52 | 353.9 | 385.2667 |
| 6 | WBURB-1 | CCGT | 8.5 | 7 | 7 | 0 | NaN | CCGT | 229.4264 | 300.9212 | ... | 360.4287 | 366.122 | 341.8568 | 331.9556 | 333.214 | 309.8152 | 318.2284 | 264.954 | 248.2656 | 239.0348 |
| 7 | PEMB-31 | CCGT | 8.666667 | 8 | 8 | 0 | NaN | CCGT | 331.35 | 378.45 | ... | 426.7333 | 426.9 | 426.6333 | 426.8667 | 410.9333 | 387.7 | 395.6 | 338.4167 | 350.72 | 328.44 |
| 8 | GRMO-1 | CCGT | 10 | 9 | 9 | 1 | NaN | CCGT | 105.9033 | 105.4733 | ... | 104.5867 | 104.6167 | 104.5567 | 104.58 | 104.4867 | 104.27 | 104.0033 | 103.9633 | 103.9567 | 103.77 |
| 9 | PEMB-11 | CCGT | 10.83333 | 10 | 10 | 1 | NaN | CCGT | 435.2667 | 434 | ... | 397.8333 | 417.2667 | 424.7 | 380.8 | 371.92 | 401.6 | 356.7 | 430.2 | 437.4667 | 427.7333 |
| 10 | STAY-1 | CCGT | 12 | 11 | 11 | 1 | NaN | CCGT | 215.05 | 237.25 | ... | 355.95 | 399.64 | 369.56 | 338.48 | 341.48 | 320.76 | 314.64 | 288.76 | 268.64 | 253.16 |
| 11 | GRAI-7 | CCGT | 14.5 | 12 | 12 | 1 | NaN | CCGT | 360.05 | 426.9 | ... | 402.9833 | 380.9667 | 401.6 | 351.34 | 404.475 | 409.325 | 397.775 | 312.025 | 352.25 | 335.2 |
| 12 | DIDCB6 | CCGT | 15.33333 | 13 | 13 | 1 | NaN | CCGT | 391.3333 | 389.1333 | ... | 683.24 | 679.64 | 643.48 | 574.76 | 505.86 | 514.8 | 467.6 | 349.9 | 477.2 | 468.8 |
| 13 | STAY-4 | CCGT | 15.83333 | 14 | 14 | 1 | NaN | CCGT | 360.4 | 362.6 | ... | 422.3 | 422.5833 | 422.4667 | 353.0167 | 360.375 | 424.7667 | 419.3333 | 376 | 261.8667 | 313.85 |
| 14 | SCCL-3 | CCGT | 15.83333 | 14 | 14 | 1 | NaN | CCGT | 308.6 | 357.75 | ... | 327.65 | 351.42 | 317.92 | 288.26 | 355.025 | 307.575 | 345.4333 | 327.2333 | 266.8333 | 350.3 |
| 15 | CDCL-1 | CCGT | 16 | 15 | 15 | 1 | NaN | CCGT | 270.63 | 255.24 | ... | 353.55 | 370.53 | 383.16 | 346.08 | 391.14 | 290.97 | 217.656 | 184.212 | 220.815 | 271.98 |
| 16 | STAY-3 | CCGT | 16.16667 | 16 | 16 | 1 | NaN | CCGT | 272.9667 | 246.7667 | ... | 419.0833 | 425.3833 | 394.4 | 373.1167 | 248.0167 | 434.45 | 434.3 | 434.6 | 412.65 | 384.7 |
| 17 | MRWD-1 | CCGT | 17.25 | 17 | 17 | 1 | NaN | CCGT | 560.2667 | 596.8667 | ... | 858.35 | 798.65 | 753.5 | 708.85 | 673.4 | 661.6 | 584.65 | 412 | 496.8667 | 523 |
| 18 | WBURB-3 | CCGT | 18 | 18 | 18 | 2 | NaN | CCGT | 311.726 | 427.676 | ... | 391.3835 | 397.5085 | 366.775 | 323.953 | 387.526 | 352.2873 | 271.3773 | 220.964 | 210.3973 | 206.59 |
| 19 | WBURB-2 | CCGT | 19.2 | 19 | 19 | 2 | NaN | CCGT | 295.54 | 424.56 | ... | 408.068 | 363.544 | 352.572 | 350.844 | 311.796 | 194.212 | 188.7867 | 238.43 | 278.67 | 235.14 |
| 20 | GYAR-1 | CCGT | 19.6 | 20 | 20 | 2 | NaN | CCGT | 404.328 | 404.328 | ... | 285.7976 | 405.96 | 307.4067 | 405.85 | 405.552 | 405.651 | 258.035 | 405.75 | 404.756 | 406.148 |
| 21 | STAY-2 | CCGT | 20.16667 | 21 | 21 | 2 | NaN | CCGT | 275.2 | 435.4 | ... | 380.5667 | 424.76 | 425.56 | 288.46 | 430.5 | 431.3 | 431.3 | 429.9 | 413.4 | 366.9 |
| 22 | SHOS-1 | CCGT | 21.66667 | 22 | 22 | 2 | NaN | CCGT | 317.998 | 344.798 | ... | 359.1892 | 364.7316 | 353.3156 | 348.34 | 315.8628 | 288.662 | 333.9633 | 332.5593 | 351.1827 | 324.1347 |
| 23 | KLYN-A-1 | CCGT | 22.2 | 23 | 23 | 2 | NaN | CCGT | 382.584 | 382.502 | ... | 333.674 | 373.6155 | 324.716 | 373.8213 | 363.064 | 299.9207 | 274.685 | 380.882 | 380.74 | 381.804 |
| 24 | DIDCB5 | CCGT | 22.33333 | 24 | 24 | 2 | NaN | CCGT | 582.2 | 584.6 | ... | 722.5333 | 634 | 511.4667 | 724.4 | 726.3 | 708.1 | 722.4 | 585.9 | 355.5 | 589 |
| 25 | CARR-1 | CCGT | 22.4 | 25 | 25 | 2 | NaN | CCGT | 221.2 | 240.4 | ... | 355.68 | 357.76 | 302.36 | 318.55 | 352.8 | 338.35 | 373.85 | 354.8 | 211.6 | 228.1333 |
| 26 | LAGA-1 | CCGT | 22.66667 | 26 | 26 | 2 | NaN | CCGT | 374.55 | 474.0667 | ... | 818 | 786.72 | 588.48 | 534.7 | 720.8 | 689.7333 | 661.8 | 647.0667 | 608.6 | 538.0667 |
| 27 | CARR-2 | CCGT | 23 | 27 | 27 | 3 | NaN | CCGT | 177.2 | 183.9 | ... | 268.1667 | 312.08 | 287.32 | 262.04 | 275.56 | 287.4 | 311.24 | 309.72 | 138.84 | 192.7 |
| 28 | GRAI-8 | CCGT | 23.66667 | 28 | 28 | 3 | NaN | CCGT | 333.45 | 377.7 | ... | 361.9 | 408.85 | 402.025 | 402.45 | 393.85 | 370.35 | 355.525 | 258.8 | 273.2 | 339.4 |
| 29 | SCCL-2 | CCGT | 24.5 | 29 | 29 | 3 | NaN | CCGT | 337 | 321.2 | ... | 314.8 | 383.25 | 372.05 | 369.85 | 366.05 | 381.7 | 392.85 | 360.25 | 274.4 | 390.4 |
| 30 | LBAR-1 | CCGT | 25.75 | 30 | 30 | 3 | NaN | CCGT | 0 | 0 | ... | 692.88 | 600.03 | 690.0133 | 566.42 | 692.79 | 514.42 | 653.86 | 315.98 | 0 | 0 |
| 31 | CNQPS-2 | CCGT | 27.5 | 31 | 31 | 3 | NaN | CCGT | 0 | 0 | ... | 307.7865 | 308.133 | 305.802 | 305.2035 | 235.7775 | 244.125 | 243.558 | 76.104 | 0 | 0 |
| 32 | SPLN-1 | CCGT | 27.66667 | 32 | 32 | 3 | NaN | CCGT | 350.7 | 343.9 | ... | 671.4667 | 567.7 | 808.6 | 712 | 574.55 | 350.25 | 664.7 | 567.3 | 468.3 | 348.3 |
| 33 | CNQPS-1 | CCGT | 29 | 33 | 33 | 3 | NaN | CCGT | 0 | 0 | ... | 349.902 | 350.28 | 350.028 | 175.896 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 34 | DAMC-1 | CCGT | 29 | 33 | 33 | 3 | NaN | CCGT | 513.81 | 491.4 | ... | 690.9975 | 683.64 | 668.655 | 653.265 | 487.2825 | 402.21 | 473.31 | 325.485 | 523.26 | 563.49 |
| 35 | KEAD-2 | CCGT | 30 | 34 | 34 | 3 | NaN | CCGT | 0 | 0 | ... | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 36 | HUMR-1 | CCGT | 31.16667 | 35 | 35 | 3 | NaN | CCGT | 207.0053 | 171.1883 | ... | 535.9217 | 528.3143 | 492.4373 | 430.5817 | 393.7937 | 379.3843 | 327.5003 | 283.7973 | 274.634 | 251.072 |
| 37 | SHBA-1 | CCGT | 32.2 | 36 | 36 | 4 | NaN | CCGT | 0 | 0 | ... | 638.16 | 579.0908 | 435.028 | 476.571 | 426 | 280.142 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 38 | SEAB-1 | CCGT | 33 | 37 | 37 | 4 | NaN | CCGT | 0 | 0 | ... | 605.4667 | 482.5333 | 404.596 | 639 | 602.1 | 558.8 | 332.783 | 4.458 | 0 | 0 |
| 39 | CNQPS-4 | CCGT | 33.4 | 38 | 38 | 4 | NaN | CCGT | 0 | 0 | ... | 322.602 | 306.054 | 305.634 | 242.508 | 138.537 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 40 | PETEM1 | CCGT | 35 | 39 | 39 | 4 | NaN | CCGT | 0 | 0 | ... | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 41 | SEAB-2 | CCGT | 35.75 | 40 | 40 | 4 | NaN | CCGT | 0 | 0 | ... | 342.4067 | 311.34 | 305.6533 | 262.334 | 261.9 | 252.27 | 294.62 | 180.467 | 167.52 | 0 |
| 42 | COSO-1 | CCGT | 36 | 41 | 41 | 4 | NaN | CCGT | 0 | 0 | ... | 694.287 | 604.765 | 489.278 | 339.022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 43 | ROCK-1 | CCGT | 36.6 | 42 | 42 | 4 | NaN | CCGT | 160.6 | 188.4 | ... | 211.5 | 297.1 | 282.5 | 247 | 276 | 210.2 | 210 | 210.4 | 123.8 | 114.4 |
| 44 | WBURB-43 | COAL | 37.5 | 43 | 1 | NaN | 0 | COAL | 1.169 | 1.0524 | ... | 0.816 | 0.6685 | 0.596667 | 0.634 | 1.246 | 0.206 | 0.88 | 0.012 | 0.7455 | 1 |
| 45 | WBURB-41 | COAL | 38.5 | 44 | 2 | NaN | 0 | COAL | 0.86 | 0.8396 | ... | 0.61 | 0.547 | 0.484667 | 0.484 | 0.948 | 0.162 | 0.714 | 0.04 | 0.5765 | 0.427 |
| 46 | FELL-1 | CCGT | 39.66667 | 45 | 43 | 4 | NaN | CCGT | 1.162667 | 1.158667 | ... | 0.8 | 0.704 | 0.746 | 0.642 | 1.497 | 1.0564 | 0.938 | 0.632 | 1.146 | 0.97 |
| 47 | FDUNT-1 | CCGT | 40 | 46 | 44 | 4 | NaN | CCGT | 0 | 0 | ... | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 48 | KEAD-1 | CCGT | 43 | 47 | 45 | 4 | NaN | CCGT | 0 | 0 | ... | 344.96 | 219.46 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

This dataframe (DF1) will stay constant and is a total of the days within the dataset. I need to apply some conditions to this and the next dataframe to create my target dataframe. Here the results will loop through each row for each unit and period first static and then for each day.

My next dataframe is ("single_day_fossil"):

|  | settlementPeriod | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | ... | 39 | 40 | 41 | 42 | 43 | 44 | 45 | 46 | 47 | 48 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| settlementDate | Type |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 03/01/2022 | Fossil | 2540.1 | 2884.05 | 2322.026 | 2027.544 | 2043.558 | 1967.35 | 2050.054 | 1917.484 | 1948.606 | 1912.418 | ... | 10306.18 | 9785.316 | 8583.608 | 7625.128 | 6738.098 | 5965.298 | 5475.074 | 4584.388 | 3761.072 | 2774.104 |
|  | ZE | 18190.57 | 18261.24 | 18367.98 | 18198.04 | 18072.02 | 17601.21 | 18000.11 | 17395.08 | 17019.21 | 17107.83 | ... | 18978.73 | 18166.97 | 18327.11 | 18367.1 | 18085.1 | 17580.44 | 17604.15 | 17417.96 | 17043.72 | 17014.03 |
| 04/01/2022 | Fossil | 2772.004 | 3415.516 | 3534.106 | 3580.126 | 3501.394 | 3530.39 | 3518.412 | 3342.706 | 3181.994 | 3146.302 | ... | 12778.29 | 12100.7 | 10426.32 | 8754.372 | 7441.266 | 5952.982 | 5218.44 | 3973.944 | 2952.536 | 2582.598 |
|  | ZE | 16883.01 | 16655.47 | 16581.57 | 16322.97 | 16027.87 | 15967.23 | 16137.86 | 16201.75 | 16585.11 | 16425.07 | ... | 21364.5 | 20575.99 | 20808.43 | 20916.99 | 20516.72 | 20159.66 | 20452.27 | 20429.92 | 19755.29 | 19376.17 |
| 05/01/2022 | Fossil | 2653.978 | 2700.036 | 2186.638 | 1702.384 | 1617.526 | 1693.336 | 1790.182 | 1808.854 | 2356.254 | 2240.072 | ... | 20383.74 | 19889.02 | 19942.02 | 19124.66 | 17746.41 | 16482.56 | 14824.02 | 13599.67 | 12724.68 | 11871.32 |
|  | ZE | 19296.58 | 19774.3 | 20163.37 | 20379.58 | 20584.48 | 20356.32 | 20292.94 | 20149.79 | 20346.74 | 20312.73 | ... | 16015.95 | 15815.97 | 14855.58 | 14335.55 | 14244.87 | 14004.69 | 13692.16 | 13079.68 | 12331.1 | 11980.89 |
| 06/01/2022 | Fossil | 11556.75 | 11924.36 | 11581.64 | 11144.16 | 11358.06 | 10916.28 | 10666.71 | 9805.292 | 8705.252 | 8236.088 | ... | 13995.8 | 12914.79 | 11053.95 | 9299.794 | 8235.534 | 6809.19 | 6129.844 | 4466.148 | 3121.212 | 2493.644 |
|  | ZE | 11850.34 | 11698 | 11801.11 | 11592.45 | 11671.91 | 12026.96 | 12344.47 | 12939.35 | 13628 | 14029.14 | ... | 20877.06 | 20382.15 | 20275.57 | 20319.9 | 19996.25 | 19829.15 | 19607.19 | 19353.83 | 18973.22 | 18558.7 |
| 07/01/2022 | Fossil | 2373.65 | 2418.446 | 2221.578 | 2154.566 | 2192.188 | 2218.626 | 2156.846 | 2143.972 | 2139.154 | 2167.03 | ... | 17639.57 | 17114.65 | 16611.99 | 15364.73 | 14183.43 | 12943.07 | 11741.8 | 10259.63 | 8082.83 | 6886.372 |
|  | ZE | 18433.11 | 17909.67 | 17774.73 | 17816.4 | 17868.83 | 17898.04 | 17780.59 | 17443.38 | 17509.98 | 17634.34 | ... | 17666.81 | 17130.19 | 16725.84 | 16512.92 | 16008.63 | 15535.5 | 15174.44 | 15117.62 | 14776.75 | 15142.52 |
| 08/01/2022 | Fossil | 6407.984 | 6529.928 | 6075.514 | 5258.582 | 4559.906 | 3852.834 | 3709.324 | 2774.442 | 3365.166 | 3216.284 | ... | 10842.58 | 9508.996 | 8120.528 | 6804.656 | 5489.058 | 4459.776 | 3705.5 | 3126.296 | 2521.558 | 2664.252 |
|  | ZE | 15237.24 | 15360.68 | 14994.3 | 14741.95 | 14695.1 | 14979.54 | 15286.45 | 15946.4 | 16088.04 | 16046.92 | ... | 18785.5 | 18778.87 | 18906.69 | 18920.12 | 18766.97 | 18589.9 | 18492.87 | 18095.51 | 17609.88 | 16721.8 |

I have a third and final dataframe which is a cumulative of my first dataframe through the following code:

```
Max_cumulative_generation = merit_order.set_index(['BM Unit ID 1','Technology_x','ave rank','rank','Technology_y']).cumsum().reset_index()
```

It has the same index as merit_order (df1) but cumulative sums as input values.

I wrote the following function to loop through each settlement period (1-48) with the idea that I can then replicate it for each day with my second function. However, It seems to only work for one date in my dataset and just loops the same output for each day as the outcome which I put into a dictionary to see. I need the function to apply the rules to each day seperately.

Function one:

```
def run_loop_for_day_SP_generation(merit_order,Max_cumulative_generation,single_day_fossil):
    modelled_gen_df = pd.DataFrame(index=merit_order.index,columns=merit_order.columns)
    for SP in single_day_fossil.columns:
        for row in merit_order.index:
            ### Next lines IF statements the same as that in the excel table Table 2.
            if row == 0:
                modelled_gen_df.loc[row,SP]=merit_order.loc[row,SP]
            elif Max_cumulative_generation.loc[row-1,SP]<single_day_fossil[SP][0]:
                if Max_cumulative_generation.loc[row-1,SP]+merit_order.loc[row,SP]>single_day_fossil[SP][0]:
                    modelled_gen_df.loc[row,SP]=single_day_fossil[SP][0] - Max_cumulative_generation.loc[row-1,SP]
                else:
                    modelled_gen_df.loc[row,SP]=merit_order.loc[row,SP]
            else:
                modelled_gen_df.loc[row,SP] = 0 
    modelled_gen_df[['BM Unit ID 1','Technology_x','ave rank','rank','Technology_y']] = merit_order[['BM Unit ID 1','Technology_x','ave rank','rank','Technology_y']]
    
    return modelled_gen_df
```

Function 2:

```
def model_all_days_generation(merit_order,Max_cumulative_generation,total_fossil_demand):
    all_dates =  total_fossil_demand.index.get_level_values(0).unique()
    modelled_generation_dictionary = {'Date':'dataframe'} ## Top label
    for date in all_dates:
        single_day_fossil = total_fossil_demand.loc[:,'Fossil',:].loc[date].to_frame().transpose()
        day_modelled_gen = run_loop_for_day_SP_generation(merit_order,Max_cumulative_generation,single_day_fossil)
        modelled_generation_dictionary[date] = day_modelled_gen
        
    return modelled_generation_dictionary
```

Can anyone advise on how to adjust the functions so it loops through all settlement periods but also all days separately. If the above is run it gives the same values so that 03/01/2022 has same values as 05/01/2022. Thanks for your time!

EDIT:

A shortened example of the desired output for partial number of units and periods in the dataset for 08/01/2022. I need the same for each date in the dataset across units and periods, which I can call on through say .loc. Hope this clears things up.

|  | BM_Unit | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FAWN-1 | 130.43 | 130.93 | 130.78 | 130.58 | 130.57 | 130.54 |
| 2 | GRAI-6 | 339.45 | 342.33 | 322.53 | 312.40 | 303.78 | 307.60 |
| 3 | EECL-1 | 363.31 | 386.71 | 364.46 | 363.31 | 363.31 | 363.38 |
| 4 | PEMB-21 | 334.40 | 419.50 | 436.70 | 441.90 | 440.50 | 415.80 |
| 5 | PEMB-51 | 370.65 | 370.45 | 359.90 | 326.25 | 326.20 | 322.65 |
| 6 | PEMB-41 | 337.00 | 423.40 | 423.10 | 427.50 | 427.00 | 419.00 |
| 7 | WBURB-1 | 240.41 | 293.17 | 252.27 | 256.51 | 261.65 | 253.44 |
| 8 | PEMB-31 | 297.73 | 360.27 | 355.40 | 357.07 | 358.67 | 353.07 |
| 9 | GRMO-1 | 106.62 | 106.11 | 105.96 | 106.00 | 106.00 | 105.98 |
| 10 | PEMB-11 | 432.80 | 430.40 | 430.70 | 431.90 | 432.10 | 429.30 |

Comment: You'll likely be able to get better help with this by 1) carving down the dataframes into smaller examples, 2) providing a `df = pd.DataFrame(...)` definition for it, and 3) including what you want the output to be. Right now, your question involves a lot of extraneous data and an unclear desired outcome.

Comment: Thank you for your comment - I have tried doing so with smaller examples of the data and as you mentioned the desired outcome but the issue is that it then doesn't quite explain why I am doing what I am doing and is often unclear as to the need for say a function. What I am after is in the function as I have shown. I need to identify why it is not looping through as I thought.

Comment: @Randy I should specify I mean in previous posts.

Comment: @Randy I have simplified the issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74547501/best-way-to-pass-multiple-conditions-in-pandas-between-dataframes