# Best way to pass multiple conditions in pandas between dataframes

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a model I am building and in the test version I am stuck on how to pass multiple conditions to generate a new dataframe from existing ones. I currently have an inefficient function that loops through my dataframes one for each period (1-5) and one for each date in the dataset.

I have created a subset of the data for illustration of my problem so that it is a little less clunky to understand my problem based on feedback from previous users. In my actual dataset I have multiple IDs, periods 1-48 and many more dates.

I am trying to pass through conditions between three dataframes to generate a new one that will later be fed into a new part of my model. I have the completed model in excel but now translating it in pandas. In excel the solution is using nested IF statements with sums.

What I am trying to do is apply to following conditions to my below dataframes:

```
    For every settlement period (1-10) on each row I need to assess the following conditions:
        if the cumulative sum (from dataframe 2) is < value x in dataframe 3 (fossil)
AND
        if the cumulative sum (from dataframe 2) + the relating value from dataframe one is > value x in dataframe 3 (fossil)
        THEN: value x in dataframe 3 - the cumulative sum value (from dataframe 2) 
        otherwise: value from dataframe 1
```

Dataframes:

DF1

| Index | BM Unit ID | Technology | Rank | Gas_Quantile | Coal_Quantile | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ID 1 | Gas | 1 | 0 |  | 130.4332 | 130.932 | 130.78 | 130.58 | 130.568 |
| 1 | ID 2 | Gas | 2 | 0 |  | 339.45 | 342.325 | 322.525 | 312.4 | 303.775 |
| 2 | ID 3 | Gas | 3 | 1 |  | 363.312 | 386.712 | 364.464 | 363.312 | 363.312 |
| 3 | ID 4 | Coal | 4 |  | 0 | 334.4 | 419.5 | 436.7 | 441.9 | 440.5 |
| 4 | ID 5 | Gas | 5 | 1 |  | 370.65 | 370.45 | 359.9 | 326.25 | 326.2 |
| 5 | ID 6 | Coal | 6 |  | 0 | 337 | 423.4 | 423.1 | 427.5 | 427 |
| 6 | ID 7 | Gas | 7 | 2 |  | 240.4065 | 293.169 | 252.2675 | 256.5055 | 261.653 |
| 7 | ID 8 | Gas | 8 | 2 |  | 297.7333 | 360.2667 | 355.4 | 357.0667 | 358.6667 |
| 8 | ID 9 | Gas | 9 | 3 |  | 106.624 | 106.112 | 105.964 | 106 | 106 |
| 9 | ID 10 | Gas | 10 | 3 |  | 432.8 | 430.4 | 430.7 | 431.9 | 432.1 |

DF2

| Index | BM Unit ID | Technology | Rank | Gas_Quantile | Coal_Quantile | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ID 1 | Gas | 1 | 0 |  | 130.4332 | 130.932 | 130.78 | 130.58 | 130.568 |
| 1 | ID 2 | Gas | 2 | 0 |  | 469.8832 | 473.257 | 453.305 | 442.98 | 434.343 |
| 2 | ID 3 | Gas | 3 | 1 |  | 833.1952 | 859.969 | 817.769 | 806.292 | 797.655 |
| 3 | ID 4 | Coal | 4 |  | 0 | 1167.595 | 1279.469 | 1254.469 | 1248.192 | 1238.155 |
| 4 | ID 5 | Gas | 5 | 1 |  | 1538.245 | 1649.919 | 1614.369 | 1574.442 | 1564.355 |
| 5 | ID 6 | Coal | 6 |  | 0 | 1875.245 | 2073.319 | 2037.469 | 2001.942 | 1991.355 |
| 6 | ID 7 | Gas | 7 | 2 |  | 2115.652 | 2366.488 | 2289.737 | 2258.448 | 2253.008 |
| 7 | ID 8 | Gas | 8 | 2 |  | 2413.385 | 2726.755 | 2645.137 | 2615.514 | 2611.675 |
| 8 | ID 9 | Gas | 9 | 3 |  | 2520.009 | 2832.867 | 2751.101 | 2721.514 | 2717.675 |
| 9 | ID 10 | Gas | 10 | 3 |  | 2952.809 | 3263.267 | 3181.801 | 3153.414 | 3149.775 |

DF3

|  | settlementPeriod | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| settlementDate | Type |  |  |  |  |  |
| 03/01/2022 | Fossil | 2540.10 | 2884.05 | 2322.03 | 2027.54 | 2043.56 |
|  | ZE | 18190.57 | 18261.24 | 18367.98 | 18198.04 | 18072.02 |
| 04/01/2022 | Fossil | 2772.00 | 3415.52 | 3534.11 | 3580.13 | 3501.39 |
|  | ZE | 16883.01 | 16655.47 | 16581.57 | 16322.97 | 16027.87 |
| 05/01/2022 | Fossil | 2653.98 | 2700.04 | 2186.64 | 1702.38 | 1617.53 |
|  | ZE | 19296.58 | 19774.30 | 20163.37 | 20379.58 | 20584.48 |
| 06/01/2022 | Fossil | 11556.75 | 11924.36 | 11581.64 | 11144.16 | 11358.06 |
|  | ZE | 11850.34 | 11698.00 | 11801.11 | 11592.45 | 11671.91 |
| 07/01/2022 | Fossil | 2373.65 | 2418.45 | 2221.58 | 2154.57 | 2192.19 |
|  | ZE | 18433.11 | 17909.67 | 17774.73 | 17816.40 | 17868.83 |
| 08/01/2022 | Fossil | 6407.98 | 6529.93 | 6075.51 | 5258.58 | 4559.91 |
|  | ZE | 15237.24 | 15360.68 | 14994.30 | 14741.95 | 14695.10 |

Example desired output with one input for period one:

| Index | BM Unit ID | Technology | Rank | Gas_Quantile | Coal_Quantile | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ID 1 | Gas | 1 | 0 |  | 130.43 |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | ID 2 | Gas | 2 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | ID 3 | Gas | 3 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | ID 4 | Coal | 4 |  | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | ID 5 | Gas | 5 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | ID 6 | Coal | 6 |  | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | ID 7 | Gas | 7 | 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 | ID 8 | Gas | 8 | 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 8 | ID 9 | Gas | 9 | 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 9 | ID 10 | Gas | 10 | 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

My current solution which does not seem to be that efficient in my next step is as follows with another loop for each day in another function:

```
def run_loop_for_day_SP_generation(DF1,DF2,DF3):
    modelled_gen_df = pd.DataFrame(index=DF1.index,columns=DF1.columns)
    for SP in DF3.columns:
        for row in DF1.index:
            if row == 0:
                modelled_gen_df.loc[row,SP]=DF1.loc[row,SP]
            elif DF2.loc[row-1,SP]<DF3[SP][0]:
                if DF2.loc[row-1,SP]+DF1.loc[row,SP]>DF3[SP][0]:
                    modelled_gen_df.loc[row,SP]=DF3[SP][0] - DF2.loc[row-1,SP]
                else:
                    modelled_gen_df.loc[row,SP]=DF1.loc[row,SP]
            else:
                modelled_gen_df.loc[row,SP] = 0 
    modelled_gen_df[['BM Unit ID','Technology','ave rank','rank']] =DF1[['BM Unit ID','Technology','ave rank']]
    
    return modelled_gen_df
```

What would the most pythonic way to solve this be? using np.select?

ok more questions. 1) your conditions. there are two if statements back to back, is it "if this cond AND this cond, then x, else y?" 2) why there is only 1 value in df3 and the rest x and y? Is it just for demonstration or is it really like that? 3) you write "settlementPeriod (1-10)", with that you mean for each settlementDate Type "Fossil" right? 4) we don't know Merit_order which occurs in your function. Can't run the code like that.

Update:

There is only one value in DF3 for demonstration. Here I used X and Y to fill it in.

SettlementPeriod is the columns 1-5 as in DF1,2 and 3. Settlement date is the date of the data which is why I need a second function that then loops through all days.

Update: Second function to go through all dates

```
def model_all_days_generation(DF1,DF2,DF3):
    all_dates =  DF3.index.get_level_values(0).unique()
    modelled_generation_dictionary = {'Date':'dataframe'} ## Top label
    for date in all_dates:
        single_day_fossil = DF3.loc[:,'Fossil',:].loc[date].to_frame().transpose()
        day_modelled_gen = run_loop_for_day_SP_generation(DF1,DF2,DF3)
        modelled_generation_dictionary[date] = day_modelled_gen
        
    return modelled_generation_dictionary
```

EDIT:

Output from debug:

```
(('03/01/2022', 'Fossil'), settlementPeriod
1      2540.100
2      2884.050
3      2322.026
4      2027.544
5      2043.558
6      1967.350
7      2050.054
8      1917.484
9      1948.606
10     1912.418
11     1998.150
12     2441.200
13     3098.836
14     3052.854
15     3470.942
16     3844.768
17     4515.572
18     5700.036
19     7408.294
20     7944.532
21     7185.508
22     7200.348
23     7052.050
24     7807.184
25     8065.094
26     8011.100
27     8355.068
28     8567.930
29     8657.718
30     8810.142
31     9275.370
32     9910.762
33    10308.158
34    11240.784
35    11660.706
36    11624.170
37    11452.386
38    11219.704
39    10306.176
40     9785.316
41     8583.608
42     7625.128
43     6738.098
44     5965.298
45     5475.074
46     4584.388
47     3761.072
48     2774.104
Name: (03/01/2022, Fossil), dtype: float64)
```

Error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['1,', '2,', '3,', '4,', '5,', '6,', '7,', '8,', '9,', '10,', '11,',\n       '12,', '13,', '14,', '15,', '16,', '17,', '18,', '19,', '20,', '21,',\n       '22,', '23,', '24,', '25,', '26,', '27,', '28,', '29,', '30,', '31,',\n       '32,', '33,', '34,', '35,', '36,', '37,', '38,', '39,', '40,', '41,',\n       '42,', '43,', '44,', '45,', '46,', '47,', '48'],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: does your code produce the desired output (just in an unefficient way)?

Comment: Yes and then when I need to do the next steps it becomes very illogical to implement esp when introducing a larger dataset

Comment: ok more questions. 1) your conditions. there are two if statements back to back, is it "if this cond AND this cond, then x, else y?" 2) why there is only 1 value in df3 and the rest x and y? Is it just for demonstration or is it really like that? 3) you write "settlementPeriod (1-10)", with that you mean for each settlementDate Type "Fossil" right? 4) we don't know `Merit_order` which occurs in your function. Can't run the code like that.

Comment: btw, no need to answer that in the comments, I think it's better to just update your question.

Comment: Updated the original post

Comment: ok. still didn't add/explain what `merit_order` is? I guess it is a dataframe but we don't know.

Comment: I have made the changes in the code directly. It should be DF1.

Comment: sorry to complain again, but your provided example isn't enough. I had a closer look and the one number you show in your desired output is just the same number as in df1 (in your function it is just the beginning where `if row==0`). You can reduce the rows of all of the df's, reduce the number of Dates in df3, but you need to provide all numbers (instead of `x` and `y`) to make it reproducible and also to follow your logic.. At the moment I still try to figure out what you are trying to achieve without success.

Comment: Good point - again this is an issue with the type of data I used as demonstration from my sample. In my actual data the first few point will be similar to DF1 and will only be different in the unit id's that are lower down my list not shown here. I think I just needed help on the logical bit. In any case I have filled in the rest of DF3. Thank you again.

Comment: ok, I think I got the logic of that function now. Since that result in a new DataFrame, you will get for each Date in DF3 an own DataFrame, right?

Comment: That's correct. I then have another function that loops through each day that I have added to the original post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249860/discussion-between-chetan-patel-and-rabinzel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my approach to your task:

The function `choices` will calculate the new values of the columns 1-5 with its conditions.
The function `each_date` will calculate that new dataframe for each date where `Type == 'Fossil'`

```
cols = list('12345')
# ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'] # predefine all columns you need here 

def choices(c, thresh):
    col = c.name
    thresh = thresh[col]
    
    cond1 = df2[col].shift() < thresh
    cond2 = (df2[col].shift() + df1[col]) > thresh     
    m1 = cond1 & cond2
    m2 = cond1 & (~cond2)
    m3 = ~cond1
    #no need to definde m1, m2, m3 here, but easier to read imo
    
    cond = [m1, m2, m3]
    choices = [thresh - df2[col].shift(), df1[col], 0]
    return np.select(cond, choices) # Series with the length of df1


def each_date(row):
    tmp = df1[cols].apply(choices, thresh=row) # choices will be applied per column
    tmp.loc[0, :] = df1.loc[0,cols] # values of the first row of the new df get values of df1
    return tmp
```

```
#create your dictionary
modelled_generation_dictionary = {'Date':'dataframe'}

#loop through each row, apply `each_date` on each row (which is a Series) and concat some columns to it, I assumed you want to have Unit ID and Technology with it
for row in df3.loc[df3.index.get_level_values(1)=='Fossil'].iterrows():
    print(row) # for debugging
    res = pd.concat([df1[["BM Unit ID", "Technology"]], each_date(row[1])],axis=1)

    # change key from timestamp to Date only and make it a string for format like: "2022-03-01"
    modelled_generation_dictionary[f"{row[0][0].date()}"] = res

print(modelled_generation_dictionary)
```

For debugging: I added the row `print(row)`, each row should be a tuple, containing a tuple as 1st element (with two elements, 1st the timestamp, 2nd the Type) and the 2nd element a `pandas.Series`, like this:

```
((Timestamp('2022-03-01 00:00:00'), 'Fossil'), 1    2540.10
2    2884.05
3    2322.03
4    2027.54
5    2043.56
Name: (2022-03-01 00:00:00, Fossil), dtype: float64)
```

Output of that dict:

```
Date
dataframe

2022-03-01
   Index BM Unit ID Technology         1         2         3        4        5
0      0       ID 1        Gas  130.4332  130.9320  130.7800  130.580  130.568
1      1       ID 2        Gas  339.4500  342.3250  322.5250  312.400  303.775
2      2       ID 3        Gas  363.3120  386.7120  364.4640  363.312  363.312
3      3       ID 4       Coal  334.4000  419.5000  436.7000  441.900  440.500
4      4       ID 5        Gas  370.6500  370.4500  359.9000  326.250  326.200
5      5       ID 6       Coal  337.0000  423.4000  423.1000  427.500  427.000
6      6       ID 7        Gas  240.4065  293.1690  252.2675   25.598   52.205
7      7       ID 8        Gas  297.7333  360.2667   32.2930    0.000    0.000
8      8       ID 9        Gas  106.6240  106.1120    0.0000    0.000    0.000
9      9      ID 10        Gas   20.0910   51.1830    0.0000    0.000    0.000

2022-04-01
   Index BM Unit ID Technology         1         2         3         4         5
0      0       ID 1        Gas  130.4332  130.9320  130.7800  130.5800  130.5680
1      1       ID 2        Gas  339.4500  342.3250  322.5250  312.4000  303.7750
2      2       ID 3        Gas  363.3120  386.7120  364.4640  363.3120  363.3120
3      3       ID 4       Coal  334.4000  419.5000  436.7000  441.9000  440.5000
4      4       ID 5        Gas  370.6500  370.4500  359.9000  326.2500  326.2000
5      5       ID 6       Coal  337.0000  423.4000  423.1000  427.5000  427.0000
6      6       ID 7        Gas  240.4065  293.1690  252.2675  256.5055  261.6530
7      7       ID 8        Gas  297.7333  360.2667  355.4000  357.0667  358.6667
8      8       ID 9        Gas  106.6240  106.1120  105.9640  106.0000  106.0000
9      9      ID 10        Gas  251.9910  430.4000  430.7000  431.9000  432.1000

2022-05-01
   Index BM Unit ID Technology         1        2        3        4        5
0      0       ID 1        Gas  130.4332  130.932  130.780  130.580  130.568
1      1       ID 2        Gas  339.4500  342.325  322.525  312.400  303.775
2      2       ID 3        Gas  363.3120  386.712  364.464  363.312  363.312
3      3       ID 4       Coal  334.4000  419.500  436.700  441.900  440.500
4      4       ID 5        Gas  370.6500  370.450  359.900  326.250  326.200
5      5       ID 6       Coal  337.0000  423.400  423.100  127.938   53.175
6      6       ID 7        Gas  240.4065  293.169  149.171    0.000    0.000
7      7       ID 8        Gas  297.7333  333.552    0.000    0.000    0.000
8      8       ID 9        Gas  106.6240    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000
9      9      ID 10        Gas  133.9710    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000

2022-06-01
   Index BM Unit ID Technology         1         2         3         4         5
0      0       ID 1        Gas  130.4332  130.9320  130.7800  130.5800  130.5680
1      1       ID 2        Gas  339.4500  342.3250  322.5250  312.4000  303.7750
2      2       ID 3        Gas  363.3120  386.7120  364.4640  363.3120  363.3120
3      3       ID 4       Coal  334.4000  419.5000  436.7000  441.9000  440.5000
4      4       ID 5        Gas  370.6500  370.4500  359.9000  326.2500  326.2000
5      5       ID 6       Coal  337.0000  423.4000  423.1000  427.5000  427.0000
6      6       ID 7        Gas  240.4065  293.1690  252.2675  256.5055  261.6530
7      7       ID 8        Gas  297.7333  360.2667  355.4000  357.0667  358.6667
8      8       ID 9        Gas  106.6240  106.1120  105.9640  106.0000  106.0000
9      9      ID 10        Gas  432.8000  430.4000  430.7000  431.9000  432.1000

2022-07-01
   Index BM Unit ID Technology         1        2        3        4        5
0      0       ID 1        Gas  130.4332  130.932  130.780  130.580  130.568
1      1       ID 2        Gas  339.4500  342.325  322.525  312.400  303.775
2      2       ID 3        Gas  363.3120  386.712  364.464  363.312  363.312
3      3       ID 4       Coal  334.4000  419.500  436.700  441.900  440.500
4      4       ID 5        Gas  370.6500  370.450  359.900  326.250  326.200
5      5       ID 6       Coal  337.0000  423.400  423.100  427.500  427.000
6      6       ID 7        Gas  240.4065  293.169  184.111  152.628  200.835
7      7       ID 8        Gas  257.9980   51.962    0.000    0.000    0.000
8      8       ID 9        Gas    0.0000    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000
9      9      ID 10        Gas    0.0000    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000

2022-08-01
   Index BM Unit ID Technology         1         2         3         4         5
0      0       ID 1        Gas  130.4332  130.9320  130.7800  130.5800  130.5680
1      1       ID 2        Gas  339.4500  342.3250  322.5250  312.4000  303.7750
2      2       ID 3        Gas  363.3120  386.7120  364.4640  363.3120  363.3120
3      3       ID 4       Coal  334.4000  419.5000  436.7000  441.9000  440.5000
4      4       ID 5        Gas  370.6500  370.4500  359.9000  326.2500  326.2000
5      5       ID 6       Coal  337.0000  423.4000  423.1000  427.5000  427.0000
6      6       ID 7        Gas  240.4065  293.1690  252.2675  256.5055  261.6530
7      7       ID 8        Gas  297.7333  360.2667  355.4000  357.0667  358.6667
8      8       ID 9        Gas  106.6240  106.1120  105.9640  106.0000  106.0000
9      9      ID 10        Gas  432.8000  430.4000  430.7000  431.9000  432.1000
```

Comment: Thanks - I am getting a key error on the dictionary function:
KeyError: "None of [Index(['1,', '2,', '3,', '4,', '5,', '6,', '7,', '8,', '9,', '10,', '11,',\n       '12,', '13,', '14,', '15,', '16,', '17,', '18,', '19,', '20,', '21,',\n       '22,', '23,', '24,', '25,', '26,', '27,', '28,', '29,', '30,', '31,',\n       '32,', '33,', '34,', '35,', '36,', '37,', '38,', '39,', '40,', '41,',\n       '42,', '43,', '44,', '45,', '46,', '47,', '48'],\n      dtype='object', name='settlementPeriod')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: It's highlighting line 6 (each_date(row[1])])

Comment: Did you copy paste exactly mz code? It should search for 1 to 48 in the index. Not in de columns.

Comment: I edited my answer, check if `row` looks the same for you.

Comment: I have added info on the post. The solution returns the tuple for one day but still returns no DF and the same error

Comment: Try without the concat, like: `res=each_date(row[1])` then we see if the function itself works.

Comment: That returns the same error.

Comment: To confirm in the first function I have made the following change: cols = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48']

Comment: yes, I assumed that. come to the chat room from earlier