# Can I use np.where to create a new dataframe from two or more existing dataframes of different sizes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Is it possible to do so using just np.where with multiple conditions?

Comment: Give a [mcve] - a couple of small frames, the code you've tried (without or without `where`), and what you seek.  `np.where` isn't a "magical" frame maker.  It's only as good as the 3 arguments - the condition, and the 2 alternatives.  With different sizes you'll probably get 'broadcasting' errors, since it can't match up indices.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have tried to post the issue previously but I think due to the complexity of my question it has not been picked up on. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74547501/best-way-to-pass-multiple-conditions-in-pandas-between-dataframes Here it is where I am trying to apply np.where

Comment: `np.where` is not an iterator.  Python evaluates the condition array (or frame), and each of the 2 arguments, and passes the results to `where`.  `where` just selects between values.  There are many SO questions about using `np.where` with `pandas`.  As for your earlier question - I, and possibly others, have something like a 30 second attention span.  If I can't grasp the essence of a problem with a quick read, I move on to something else.

Comment: Someone else just asked about using `np.where` with different size frames, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74551555/conditionally-match-two-dataframes-of-unequal-size

Comment: Thank you. I will read and then try to post again with a better explanation of my problem. Immediately I see I haven’t specified that the solution I am after is something that needs to iterate through different chunks of data so will try to develop a sample data set that’s not to complex to post with